# Left Join With Null value

Tags: sql, oracle11g

tbl1 Is

```
id|name_x|other_column_x
________________________
1 | x    |eeeee
1 | y    |eeeee
1 | z    |eeeee
2 | y    |eeeee
2 | p    |eeee
```

tbl2 Is

```
id|name_y|other_column_y
________________________
1 | aa  |nnn
2 | dd  |nnn
2 | ee  |nnn
```

I Want This Result

```
id|name_x|name_y|other_column_x|other_column_y
______________________________________________
1 | x    | aa   |eeee          |nnn
1 | y    |null  |eeee          |null
1 | z    |null  |eeee          |null
2 | y    | dd   |eeee          |nnn
2 | p    | ee   |eeee          |nnn
```

I Write This Query

```
Select x.id,x.name_x,y.name_y 
From tbl1 x left join tbl2 y on x.id=y.id
```

But This Query Return

```
id|name_x|name_y|other_column_x|other_column_y
______________________________________________
1 | x    | aa   |eeee          |nnn
1 | y    | aa   |eeee          |nnn
1 | a    | aa   |eeee          |nnn
2 | y    | dd   |eeee          |nnn
2 | p    | ee   |eeee          |nnn
```

I want return null for name_y column if number rows tbl2 less than tbl1...

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=17707b1cd47b154dd99f7e0ba377fae3)*

Comment: The problem is that the id value 1 is repeated. How do you decide which name_x it is that is supposed to have the name_y?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want to take ordering into account.  However, your table does not have an ordering column, so the match may vary with your data.

The idea is to use `row_number()` for the matching:

```
select t1.id, t1.name_x, t2.name_y,
       t1.other_column_x, t2.other_column_y
from (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by name_x) as seqnum
      from tbl1 t1
     ) t1 left join
     (select t2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by name_y) as seqnum
      from tbl2 t2
     ) t2
     on t1.id = t2.id and t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=09f493e382448436e406b04f6ceef409) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for Answer. this query is like 'inner join' and does not return all row of tbl1

Comment: I add query to https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=17707b1cd47b154dd99f7e0ba377fae3 please help me

Comment: @ashkufaraz . . . It is using a `left join` with no filtering.  It returns all rows from the first table.  I added a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You need an additional criteria in the `left join` conditions to restrict the matches. Based on your sample data, this *might be*:

```
select x.id,x.name_x,y.name_y 
from tbl1 x 
left join tbl2 y on x.id = y.id and y.name_y like x.name_x || '%'
```

Comment: thanks for answer.I update my question.name_x and name_y are not like...

Comment: I add query to https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=17707b1cd47b154dd99f7e0ba377fae3 please help me

Answer (score 1):

You should add 1 more joining condition based on pattern that you are looking from first table

```
Select x.id,x.name_x,y.name_y 
From tbl1 x 
left join tbl2 y 
on 
x.id=y.id and 
y.name_y like x.name_x + '%'
```

You can achieve the similar thing with case statement also

```
 Select x.id,
        x.name_x,
         case when y.name_y like x.name_x + '%' then y.name_y
         else Null END
From tbl1 x 
left join tbl2 y 
on 
x.id=y.id
```

Comment: thanks for answer.I update my question.name_x and name_y are not like...